# Get parameter from URL in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am working on SPA (Vue JS) and Laravel as API. I want when users will receive email to click on button that will sent them to specific route (already implemented).

So now i am struggling how to get the user id from the Vue JS part.

```
https://domain.test/admin/users/dashboard/user/65/show
```

65 from the URL is the user ID, so any idea how to extract that ID with java script from Vue JS?

I am not using vue router, this is Laravel route and Vue JS component is rendered from blade file.

I have implemented something like this bellow, but client refused...

```
https://domain.test/admin/users/dashboard/user/show?userId=65
```

Comment: Is `/admin/users/dashboard/user/65/show` a front-end (Vue) route? If so, how have you defined it in vue-router? If not, then your question is really unclear

Comment: const id = url.split('/').slice(-2)[0]

Comment: Thank you @symlink !! I wasn't thinking for something that simple... :-)

Comment: He specifically mentions he's not using Vue Router

Comment: console.log(this.$route);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let id = window.location.href.split('/').slice(-2)[0]
```

Comment: I'd highly recommend not doing this.  It couples your component to the exact route it's used on, making it impossible to reuse the component, and making it incredibly likely that someone breaks this in the future.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer! Would be nice with a short explanation of your answer and not just code.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already rendering the page in a Blade file, you should already have access to the user ID server side.

In that case, simply add the variable server side.  For example:

```
<a :href="'https://domain.test/admin/users/dashboard/user/' + {{ 
$user->id }} + '/show'">Go to Dashboard</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get parmeters from url you can use vue router for that like this:

```
const routes = [
    // dynamic segments start with a colon
    { path: '/users/:id', component: User },
  ]

const User = {
  template: '<div>User {{ $route.params.id }}</div>',
}
```

Here is the link for more examples and vue router documentation:

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html

You can also get parameters with only vanilla JavaScripe like follow:

```
const queryString = window.location.search;
console.log(queryString);
// ?product=shirt&color=blue&newuser&size=m

//then you have to parse the url
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);

const color = urlParams.get('color')
console.log(color);
// blue
```